# moment-timezone optimization with webpack

Tags: webpack, momentjs

I try excluding the latest.json file that moment-timezone uses, and use my own that only includes the time zones you need. To reduce my webpack output.

in webpack config.plugins i tried:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /moment-timezone\/data\/packed\/latest\.json/,
    require.resolve('./timezones/timezone-definitions.json')
)
```

but no success. I still get the latest.json file that moment-timezone uses. I don't get any error in console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/364#issuecomment-450692168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using the webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin() solution but it did not work then I found the comment from the link below and used alias. It worked.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8105#issuecomment-425823174

```
resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".svg", ".json"],
        alias: {
            [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json")]:
                path.resolve(__dirname, "src/common/timezone-definitions.json")
        }
    }
```

Make sure you add `.json` to the `resolve.extensions` array.

Comment: Have you tried the above solution? If it worked for you, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack you might be interested using [moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gilmoreorless/moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin) to optimize moment-timezone latest.json

You can limit the data to be included from the latest.json by:

- selecting a year range
- selecting regions, countries...

**Example including a set of zones**:

```
const MomentTimezoneDataPlugin = require('moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MomentTimezoneDataPlugin({
        matchZones: [/^Australia/, 'Pacific/Auckland', 'Etc/UTC'],
        startYear: 2000,
        endYear: 2030,
    }),
  ]
};
```

You can find more information and examples [here](https://github.com/gilmoreorless/moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin)